# Dojo: BorderContainer not showing properly when using more than one DropDownButton

Tags: dojo

I'm trying to create a layout wherein a border container with two tabs will display a series of drop down buttons. For example consider the following code snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body, html { font-family:helvetica,arial,sans-serif; font-size:90%; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dojo/dojo.xd.js" djConfig="parseOnLoad: true">
        </script>
        <script type='text/javascript'>
            dojo.require('dijit.form.DropDownButton');
            dojo.require('dijit.layout.ContentPane');
            dojo.require('dijit.layout.BorderContainer'); 
            dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
        </script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.6/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css"
        />
        <style type="text/css">
            html, body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; overflow:hidden; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body class="claro">
        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="headline" gutters="true" liveSplitters="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" splitter="true" region="center" style="width: 100%;">
                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" tabStrip="true" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
                    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My first tab" selected="true">
                         <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane">   
                             <span>Drop Down Button 1</span>
                             <span>Drop Down Button 2</span>
                        </div>
                        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="sidebar" gutters="true" liveSplitters="true" style="width: 100%; height: 95%">                         
                            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" splitter="true" region="leading" style="width: 100px;">
                                Left
                            </div>
                            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" splitter="true" region="center">
                                Center
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My second tab">
                        Lorem ipsum and all around - second...
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" splitter="true" region="bottom" style="height: 100px;">
                Bottom
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

The "Drop Down Button 1" and "Drop Down Button 2" span elements will show up nicely within the 1st tab element and above the border container within the same tab. Now if we enclose the span elements with the Dijit DropDownButton component using the code snippet below:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitIconEdit'">      
    <span>Drop Down Button 1</span>
</div>
<div dojoType="dijit.form.DropDownButton" data-dojo-props="iconClass:'dijitIconEdit'">      
    <span>Drop Down Button 2</span>
</div>
```

The tabs and the border container gets scrambled and not shown properly.

I'm using Dojo 1.6.1.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it looks like your "My first tab" should be a BorderContainer, not a ContentPane.   So that first tab has a top section (with the buttons), plus the left and center that you already have.

In other words, rather than:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My first tab" selected="true">
   <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane">   
       <span>Drop Down Button 1</span>
       <span>Drop Down Button 2</span>
   </div>
   <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" design="sidebar" gutters="true" liveSplitters="true" style="width: 100%; height: 95%">                         
       <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" splitter="true" region="leading" style="width: 100px;">
             Left
       </div>
       <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" splitter="true" region="center">
             Center
       </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

do:

```
<div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" title="My first tab" selected="true" design="headline">
  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top">   
                         <span>Drop Down Button 1</span>
                         <span>Drop Down Button 2</span>
  </div>
  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" splitter="true" region="leading" style="width: 100px;">
       Left
  </div>
  <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" splitter="true" region="center">
       Center
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Bill for replying!

Even with just using the ContentPane, the <span> elements would still show up nicely. The problem is when using dijit.form.DropDownButton for the Drop Down Buttons 1 & 2. Regardless whether the drop down buttons are placed inside a ContentPane or a BorderContainer in the sample html code I've provided, the end result is a messed up dojo interface.

Comment: What I meant is to use the code I posted above, and then change the plain <span> elements to be DropDownButton's.    As for placement, the DropDownButton's clearly need to be inside of a ContentPane, but there's no reason to make your first tab a ContentPane rather than a BorderContainer.    You may still have the same problem as before, but first things first.